# Some links not working in Chrome but working in Internet Explorer, why?

Tags: google-chrome, https, internet-explorer-8, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

The following links are not working in my chrome browser, but working on internet explorer:

> 1. https://www.coursera.org/
> 2. courses.edx.org/login
> 3. d37djvu3ytnwxt.cloudfront.net/static/images/header-logo.png

These links are working on my other pc on same internet connection. I tried updating chrome & java,disabling firewall and reinstalling chrome after clearing all cache,cookies,etc but nothing worked. I think due to some settings my chrome browser is not able to cache links from cloudfront.net, but why?. Also, I'm using Windows 8 x64

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for this problem. Here are a few troubleshooting steps you can try:

1. Clear the DNS cache: Open the command prompt and type "ipconfig /flushdns" to clear the DNS cache on your computer.
2. Disable browser extensions: Some browser extensions may interfere with certain websites. Try disabling any extensions you have installed and see if that resolves the issue.
3. Reset Chrome settings: Open Chrome settings, scroll down to the bottom, and click on "Advanced." Under the "Reset and clean up" section, select "Restore settings to their original defaults" and confirm the reset.
4. Check proxy settings: Open Chrome settings, click on "System," and then select "Open proxy settings." Ensure that no proxy settings are enabled unless required by your network.
5. Disable hardware acceleration: Open Chrome settings, scroll down to the bottom, click on "Advanced," and under the "System" section, disable "Use hardware acceleration when available."
6. Check antivirus/firewall settings: Temporarily disable any antivirus or firewall software you have installed and see if that resolves the issue. If it does, adjust the settings to allow Chrome full access.

Comment: Date & time are perfectly ok. All other websites are working, just these websites are not working in chrome but they are working in internet explorer.